# Escape characters to be used in a javascript literal string

Tags: javascript

I would like to take a string that the user will enter to a text box in a form and turn it into a javascript literal. So I'd, for instance, turn the " character into \".

Is there any complete list of characters that would need to be escaped?

Comment: What if the string is delimited using single quotes? Double quotes wouldn't need to be escaped then.

Comment: How the string is delimited is up to me.

Comment: I think "up to me" is alright. If you're very concerned, you can ask on http://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yea I just googled both and most people use "up to me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to escape your delimiter and/or whatever enclosing quotes you choose (escape double quotes if you enclose your string in double, escape single otherwise).

If you're going to render it as HTML, you may wnat to convert them to entities (e.g. `& -> &amp;`)